# Mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements when using SAVE TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I saw similar questions of this, but no one could help me to figure out my problem.
So, here is the issue:
I have the following statement:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
        print @@TRANCOUNT
        EXECUTE proc1
        print @@TRANCOUNT
COMMIT TRANSACTION

CREATE PROCEDURE proc1 AS
BEGIN
       SET XACT_ABORT ON
       SAVE TRANSACTION TillOuterMost;
       BEGIN TRANSACTION 
       print @@TRANCOUNT
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TillOuterMost;
END
GO
```

When running this I am getting error:

```
1
2
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure proc1, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 12]
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2.
2
```

Which means that `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TillOuterMost;` statement didn't decrement transaction count. Later I tried just to remove saved labeled and just used ROLLBACK TRANSACTION. But this rollbacks both inner and outer transactions and gives the following error:

```
1
2
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure proc1, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 11]
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.
0
Msg 3902, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
```

Note, that in the latter case transaction count has been decremented to 0.

I have also tried this variant which also doesn't help:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE proc1 AS
    BEGIN
       SET XACT_ABORT ON
       SAVE TRANSACTION OO
       BEGIN TRANSACTION 
       print @@TRANCOUNT
       ROLLBACK TRAN OO;
    END
    GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION AA
        print @@TRANCOUNT
        EXECUTE proc1
        if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION AA;
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
           COMMIT TRANSACTION AA
        END
```

Still getting error:

```
1
2
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure proc1, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 12]
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 2.
```

Do you have any idea how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every BEIGN must have also an END, in your case a COMMIT

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1 AS
BEGIN
       SET XACT_ABORT ON
       SAVE TRANSACTION TillOuterMost;
       BEGIN TRANSACTION 
       print @@TRANCOUNT
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TillOuterMost;
       COMMIT
END
```

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
        print @@TRANCOUNT
        EXECUTE proc1
        print @@TRANCOUNT
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

```
1
2
1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/G9F7QjG3)